# What did Ben Urich find out about Karen Page?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-2015

In Season 1 Episode 12 ("The Ones We Leave Behind") of the 2015 Daredevil series, Karen Page and Ben Urich have the following conversation:

> **Karen**: We need that story out there before it is too late.
>
> **Ben**: Could always... post it yourself on the Net. Don't need me. - [scoffs]
>
> **Karen**: And who'll believe me when they start digging? When they find... what you found... when you were looking into me.
>
> **Ben**: I'll see if I can shake loose any other sources.
>
> <sub>Transcript from [Forever Dreaming Transcripts](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?t=65503&sid=b99b7ceb9f51a3b00a547603e5d12d37)</sub>

What is Karen talking about? What did Ben find when looking into Karen? If this information is revealed in later episodes, please tag with spoilers.

Comment: I think you should say if you want to know spoilers or not.  There may or not be an arc about Karen's backstory in episodes after the one above.

Comment: Preferably spoilers would be tagged

Comment: When I watched that episode I thought that it may be a reference about Karen being a pornstar or something related. Mentioned in Daredevil #227 according to Wikipedia

Comment: This is a foreshadowing of a revelation in the [third season.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Karen_(episode))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer involves spoilers from seasons two and three.

> **Karen was involved in her brother Kevin's death.**

> [Kevin Page](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kevin_Page) died in a car accident where, officially, he was the only person in the car. In actuality, Karen was driving, but was not paying attention (in part because she had just shot her drug dealing boyfriend and they were fleeing the scene, where they'd set the trailer on fire), and flipped the car. The sheriff, wanting to spare Karen, falsified the report of the accident.

The incident was foreshadowed when Karen found a folder in Urich's old office in the season two episode "Seven Minutes in Heaven", and then portrayed in a flashback in the season three episode "Karen".

As far as I know, it's never explicitly stated that this was what Ben found, but it is heavily implied (necessary caveat that there's a decent chance they hadn't decided on what the reveal was going to be in season one when it was mentioned).

Comment: Is this ever revealed in the show?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I think the show expects you to infer it based on the evidence provided.